# How many times should I train a neural network configuration?

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying several neural network architectures (LSTM, GRU, CNN, MLP, Bidirectional LSTM, with or without attention mechanism etc) to solve a text classification problem for my dissertation. I have been running each hyperparameter configuration **10** times to pick the training session with the best results on the test set. Even with early stopping, this process is long and tedious.

Due to time and computing resources constraints, I need to reduce the number of training sessions for the next trials.

1. Could anyone suggest any procedure with less training sessions? Perhaps running 3-5 times and analyzing mean and standard deviation of the results to see if there is need to train more? Would a small SD suggest that the global minimum was found, perhaps?
2. In a real life project, do data analysts really run a grid search or a manual search with 50-100 training sessions for each hyperparameter set, according to [How many times should one train a convolutional neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291599/how-many-times-should-one-train-a-convolutional-neural-network) ? It seems extremely expensive...
3. Any suggestions of books or articles on this would also be appreciated.

Comment: you're running each hyperparameter *configuration* 10 times? or did you mean 10 configurations from the same hyperparam search space? if the former, why?

Comment: @shimao, it's your 1st question, I'm running each hyperparameter configuration 10 times to find the best performance in the test set, searching for the global minimum. I know it's expensive...